# IntelliJ IDEA keymap for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, keymaps

Is there a way to get the IntelliJ keymap for Visual Studio, like the [extension for vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here what you are looking for i think : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys

Comment: This is the link that is in the question and it only is for Visual Studio **Code**

Comment: My bad... i miss read... 
here another link : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys